# How to prove negative?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ is the PDF and CDF of a distribution, and we know $f(x)>0$ for all $x\ge0$.

Then function $c(r)$ is defined as the following equation (derived from a bellman equation):
$$c(r)-\int_{0}^{Q}c(x)f(Q+r-x){\rm d}x =F(Q+r)-1,\quad \forall\ Q>0,\ 0\leq r\leq
Q$$

Can we prove that $c(r)<0$ for all $r$?

Comment: Could you provide more context and motivation for this? Also, is the equation supposed to hold for all $Q$, or is it fixed? Finally, are we given any info about the support of the random variable, i.e. where $f(x)>0$?

Comment: Thanks. Basically, it is derived from a Bellman equation, hence it holds for all Q. Moreover, we have f(x)>0 for all x>0.

Comment: CDF is always $\leq 1.$